# How can I avoid/minimize wifi interference between router?

Tags: networking, router, wifi

I need to create 20 wireless LAN signals. To do this I will use 20 routers. 
Wifi signals have to be in the same room (will be used in that room for a especific machine). Each signal will be connected to a single wifi machine for a pair of minutes (To transfer/receive some data). 
I understand that using wifi with diferent channels I can avoid the overlapping between signals. but, Is there any form to reduce the interference between 20 wifi signals?

Comment: I think you will get better answers (not that the ones given were bad) if you give more information about what you are trying to do. Are these 20 different SSIDs? What bandwidth are you expecting? Which frequencies are available on the APs? In general, you are venturing into 'wifi hell' with what you are asking.

Comment: Yes, please tell us a lot more about what you are trying to do and why.

Answer (score 0):

If you use the 5GHz band, there are more channels to use than the 2.4 GHz band (only 3).  But you have a fundamental problem of too many transmitters and not enough channel bandwidth.  If you have 20 people in a room all taking at the same time, you have the same problem -- they will interfere with each other.

Answer (score 0):

Get a wireless controller and couple dozen APs. Twenty independent routers with wifi will be annoying to manage.

Reduce the power as much as possible. Overlap is bad on this shared medium. In particular, do not put the same channels physically adjacent to one another.

Do a site survey. Adjust AP placement, quantity and power while mapping signal.